# How to add a static file to my Windows Phone 8 project

Tags: file, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows phone 8 app and I want to include with it, an existing XML file for the app to use.

I've been spending the last few hours trying to figure out how to do this but I'm not having much luck.  The MSDN samples I am looking at seem to be all around creating a file when using the app, saving it using isolatedstorage etc, then reading it back.  I don't think this is helping me as I basically want to just add the XML file to my project now, and then have the app read it when necessary.  The file is already made and won't be re-created when the app is run, it's just some data that will ship with it.

When I right click on the Solution Explorer, select Add existing item and pick the XML file, it adds it to my project.  I don't if this is the correct way to add a "data" file that my app will need to use.  As far as I know, I'm supposed to use IsolateStorage or the latest API's for handling files so I don't know what the correct way to do this is.

What's the correct way to include a file with your project and how to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add your file as a resource.

If you created a Windows Phone app using the project template provided by Visual Studio you'll probably have a folder called Resources. Within this folder there is a AppResources.resx file. When you open this file it normally shows a table with strings. In the top left corner you can select Files. After that you can select Add Resource. VS will show a file dialog. Use this dialog to select your XML file.

From this point you can use the content of this file. E.g.

```
using NameOfProject.Resources;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show(AppResources.NameOfResource);
}
```

By default the name of the resource is the same as the name of the selected file without the extension. In the resource editor you can give it another name.

Comment: Thanks, however AppResources doesn't seem to be available in the code?  I'm getting the following error:

"The name 'AppResources' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Do you have a resource file named AppResources.resx in your project? If not, add one. In the Solution Explorer (assuming you have VS 2012) select Add New..., select category General, select Resources File and name it AppResources.resx.

Comment: Yep, I do have AppResources.resx in the Resource folder.  It was already there.  Not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Did you add the namespace of `AppResources` to the file referencing it? I did not mention this in my answer yet. Just updated it.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what was missing.